# When to use in keyword with ReadOnlyMemory or ReadOnlySpan?

Tags: c#, c#-7.3

I was wondering what would be usage of the `in` keyword with `ReadOnlyMemory<T>` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>`.

```
void Method(ReadOnlyMemory<int> memory)
{
    // Code that modifies memory wont reflect out of this scope.
    memory = memory.Slice(3);
}

void Method(in Memory<int> memory)
{
    // same thing as the above
   memory.Slice(3);
}

void Method(in ReadOnlyMemory<int> memory)
{
    // is there any performance gain here or something?
}
```

Basically  using `in` or `ReadOnly` (`Span`/`Memory`) isn't similar to `const typename &` (C++) ?

Comment: Race your horses and let us know

Comment: The second one wouldn't even compile, would it?

Comment: Oh you are right for the second one.

Comment: All methods compile. The second and third though are flagged by the [ErrorProne.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ErrorProne.NET.Structs/) analyzer as they'll result in defensive copies of the struct.

Comment: Hmm, actually, it depends on the runtime. In .NET Core 2.1 there is no perf problem. In earlier versions there is. The `xxxMemory` classes were *not* defined marked as `readonly struct` in earlier versions, which means the compiler knew the *weren't* immutable so it had to generate a defensive copy of the struct each time a property was accessed. This was [fixed in Core 2.1](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23809) due to be released next Thursday

Comment: It is a micro-optimization, the struct gets passed by reference but it does not make the effort to copy the (possibly changed) value back to the caller.  Not making the copy is a no-brainer, but you do need to find out if it is actually faster than passing by value, the normal way for small structs.  The size of the struct and how often the struct members are addressed in the method body matter.  It has only two members, so getting mileage out of in ought to be unlikely.  You can get an accidental speedup by unintentionally forcing the jitter optimizer to make better choices.